# How to allow only one checked box in the gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox, templatefield

If i have a grid view contains `checkbox` **chk_short_day** as template field :

```
<asp:GridView ID="grv_week_day" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
     CssClass="datatable" OnRowDataBound="grv_week_day_RowDataBound" >
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Height="40px" HeaderStyle-Width="200px">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <h2>week days
            </h2>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_weekday" runat="server" CssClass="title" Text='<%# Bind("WeekDay") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <HeaderStyle Height="40px" Width="100px"></HeaderStyle>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Height="40px">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <h2>Attendance Type</h2>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="drp_att" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Width="200px" Enabled="false"
                CausesValidation="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged_drp">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <HeaderStyle Height="40px"></HeaderStyle>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Height="40px">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <h2>From
            </h2>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_From" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <HeaderStyle Height="40px"></HeaderStyle>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Height="40px">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <h2>To
            </h2>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_To" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <HeaderStyle Height="40px"></HeaderStyle>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Short Day">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_short_day" runat="server" AutoPostBack ="true" OnCheckedChanged="chk_short_day_CheckedChanged"   />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

---

How to allow only one checked in the gridview , If the user check one of the check boxes ,i want to uncheck the rest automatically .?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/how-to-allow-user-to-check-only-one-row-at-a-time-in-grid-vi/

Comment: @mshsayem Question isn't tagged with JS, presumably not an option because end users can simply disable JS.

Comment: Without JS you are looking at some aweful messing around with double postbacks and hacks. C'est la ASP.NET Webforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a radio button instead? Only one radio button within the same Group are allowed to be selected.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Short Day">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:RadioButton id="rbt_short_day" GroupName="shortDay"/>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```